# FlexBoxLayoutManager orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, orientation, android-flexboxlayout

I'm working on this project where I need to display some items in columns and for that, I'm using the library from Google FlexBoxLayout.

So far, I've made it to look like this:

```
View          Recycler
x x x x x x x 0 4 8
x x x x x x x 1 5 
x x x x x x x 2 6 
x x x x x x x 3 7
```

but I want it to look like this:

```
View          Recycler
x x x x x x x 8 4 0
x x x x x x x   5 1
x x x x x x x   6 2
x x x x x x x   7 3
```

Since I'm using a RecyclerView to display those items, the FlexBoxLayoutManager doesn't let me change its `layoutDirection` to RTL. I've tried to change the recycler's layoutDirection `recycler.layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL` but it looks like it pushes the View to the left, out of the screen, just like that:

```
Recyc Empty screen
8 4 0 y y y y y y y
  5 1 y y y y y y y
  6 2 y y y y y y y
  7 3 y y y y y y y
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The problem was that I only had changed the `RecyclerView` `layoutDirection`, instead of changing the parent's `layoutDirection` (`ConstraintLayout` in my case).
Once the parent's `layoutDirection` is changed to "RTL" I just had to fix the end/start constraints of the child views. It was kinda confusing because since it's flipped, that's not as simple as it would be using the LTR orientation, but once it's done the layout seems to work as I wanted.

Hope it helps if anyone has the same issue!